# how to specifically use the global docstring?

Tags: python, global, local, docstring

I want to use the global doctstring in my command help. This a working example:

```
"""
This is a global description.

Usage:
    Use it like so::

    $ python my_fancy_script <my_fancy_name>
"""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.core.management as management

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Command(management.base.BaseCommand):
    """
    This is a local doc.
    """
    args = '<work_db_name>'
    help = globals()['__doc__']
```

This feels hacky and I was wondering is there is another way to specifically use the global docstring. Once you do

```
help = '__doc__'
```

the local description, that is, the `Command`'s docstring will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `help` is Django specific member and you need it (though I never heard of Django to interfere with built-ins),

```
help = __doc__
```

Should do the trick, this is essentially the same as `globals()['__doc__']`  because of looking for `__doc__` bubbles up to the module level scope. In the worst case, `__doc__` is `None`, then

```
help = __doc__ or Command.__doc__
```

can be used (or something like this).

If not to use `help` variable I'd go the following way:

```
""" module doc """
class C: pass
C.__doc__ = __doc__
```